Getting issue in Sending Mail with attachments in java
I have attached code and error and file permissions screen shots
 private void sendOceanDashboardSummary(String subject, String mailId, Map<String, Object> data) {
    try {
      String filePath = "C:\\Users\\Chandana\\File";
      String fileName = "Ocean_Dashboard_Summary";

      File file = new File(filePath);
      System.out.println("File exists: " + file.exists());
      System.out.println("File is readable: " + file.canRead());

      if (file.exists() && file.canRead()) {
        EmailMessageBuilder message = new EmailMessage.Builder().subject(subject)
            .withTemplate(PublicanConstants.ALERT_MAIL_TEMPLATE2, data).withHtmlContent();

        InputStream stream = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get(filePath));

        message.addFileAttachment(stream, fileName, "application/octet-stream");

        EmailMessage emailMessage = message.to(mailId).build();
        emailService.send(emailMessage);

        LOGGER.info("Email sent with the Ocean Dashboard Summary attachment.");
      } else {
        LOGGER.error("File does not exist or is not readable.");
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      LOGGER.error("Error occurred in attaching and sending the Ocean Dashboard Summary file.", e);
    }
  }

-----------------------
  String subject = "Test mail with attachments";
    String mailId = "*****";
    Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
    this.sendOceanDashboardSummary(subject, mailId, data);

I checked the file permissions.,even though not working
error image
File permissions
